# Unable to convert Matlab Timestamp to datetime in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to convert timestamp column to datetime. This is part of my data set:

```
Time,INDOOR Ambient Temp.,INDOOR Relative Humidity,INDOOR Air Velocity,INDOOR Mean Radiant Temp.,INDOOR Lumens,INDOOR CO2,Predicted Mean Vote (PMV)
735080.010417,24.584695,63.70399999999999,0.030988,24.584695,,-0.269505
735080.020833,24.584695,63.856,0.030988,24.584695,,-0.26837300000000003
```

When parsing to datetime using the following code:

```
# Load data
df = pd.read_csv("ContData.txt", parse_dates=['Time'])

# Group by day and compute the max temp per day
df.index = df['Time']

pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).apply(lambda x: x.date())

# Identify the day, month and year
df['day'] = df['Time'].map(lambda x: x.day)
df['month'] = df['Time'].map(lambda x: x.month)
df['year'] = df['Time'].map(lambda x: x.year)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: hour must be in 0..23
```

Comment: Pandas does not understand `735080.010417` as a timestamp. Neither do I. Could you explain the format.

Comment: In fact, I got the data from my boss, it is described as a Absolute time (MATLAB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab considers the origin January 0, 0000 and outputs the date as the number of days since then. This creates a bit of an issue because that's not a real date and well outside of the `datetime64[ns]` bounds. With a simple subtraction relative to the POSIX origin (1970-01-01) you can then use the vectorized `pd.to_datetime` conversion.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Additional 366 because January 0, year 0000 
offset = datetime(1970, 1, 1).toordinal() + 366  #719529

pd.to_datetime(df['Time']-offset, unit='D')
#0   2012-07-30 00:15:00.028799999
#1   2012-07-30 00:29:59.971200000
#Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Worked for me, Thanks! I added the `round` method to clean up the timestamp decimals I suppose introduced by truncation. For example, round to the nearest millisecond `pd.to_datetime(df['Time']-offset, unit='D').round('ms')` will changes *2017-08-01 00:59:59.999996672* to *2017-08-01 01:00:00*

Answer (score 1):

Since you added that it's a matlab absolute time, please try the following:

```
def datenum_to_datetime(datenum):
    """
    Convert Matlab datenum into Python datetime.
    :param datenum: Date in datenum format
    :return:        Datetime object corresponding to datenum.
    """
    days = datenum % 1
    return datetime.fromordinal(int(datenum)) \
           + timedelta(days=days) \
           - timedelta(days=366)
print(datenum_to_datetime(your_value))
```