How to import MATLAB datetime array into python?
I have a Matlab file containing an array of datetime objects with 18750 timestamps.

When I use scipy.io to import the data, it gives the following output which is very different.

I am expecting an array of timestamps just like what is seen in Matlab. Any idea how I can achieve this? Thank you very much for your time and attention.

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913301/matlab-date-string-results-in-java-lang-string-in-python-scipy-io, which said that the simplest way to do this is to export the dates as strings and grab them back with usual Python datetime.datetime methods.
TimeStamps are a date format only used by Matlab, according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48542674/how-to-read-matlab-datetimes-stored-in-a-file-using-scipy-io-loadmat

My data is Matlab Datetime datatype NOT a  1x1 java.lang.String.

Possible duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/a/18277039/3978545, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58957369/unable-to-convert-matlab-timestamp-to-datetime-in-python,

@ShivamMishra the OP of the other post is mistaken, he also has a TimeStamp object
